# Suggestion on table analyze

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.2

Environment: PostgreSQL: 9.5.15, PostGIS: 2.2.7

When analyzing a table containing GIS data, I get this output:

> ANALYZE SCHEMA.TABLE;
>
> NOTICE:  no non-null/empty features, unable to compute statistics
>
> NOTICE:  no non-null/empty features, unable to compute statistics
>
> Query returned successfully with no result in 1.1 secs.

What is the reason for the NOTICE, and can this lead to any problems in the future?

Comment: This thread may help: https://marc.info/?l=postgis-users&m=141148660502495&w=2